# Ubuntu 22.04.1 headset microphone not working

Tags: pulseaudio, 22.04, alsa, microphone

I have a Philips headset with integrated microphone. My laptop is Lenovo B590 with a single 3.5 mm jack input. When plugged in, my headset works fine except the microphone.

I reinstalled pulse audio and Alsa, did an override in Jack Reconnect and additional configs in `alsa-base.conf` for an appropriate model of my Audio Card.

I can see my headset microphone in settings but there is no sound, only noise, some clicking.
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: About the "headset": Does it have a single jack as well?

Comment: Yes, it has a single jack